# Can I send an associative array into an included Twig template?

Tags: php, include, twig, associative-array

I'm trying to send an associative array into a Twig template I am including:

```
{% include 'my-template.twig' with {
    items: [
        [
            'property' => 'value',
            'other' => 'value'
        ],
        [
            'property' => 'value',
            'other' => 'value'
        ]
    ]
} %}
```

I get this error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'An array element must be followed by a comma. Unexpected token "operator" of value "=" ("punctuation" expected with value ",")`

It would seem it doesn't like `=>`. Is it my syntax? Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7):

change associative array start and end `[]` to `{}` and keys `=>` to `:`

```
[
        {
            'property':'value',
            'other':'value'
        },
        {
            'property':'value',
            'other':'value'
        }
]
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#literals

Answer (score 2):

```
{% include 'my-template.twig' with {
    items: {
        {
            'property': 'value',
            'other': 'value'
        },
        {
            'property': 'value',
            'other': 'value'
        }
    }
} %}
```